# Parent div not expanding to children's height

Tags: css, html, height, expand

As you will see, I have a `div` (`#innerPageWrapper`) that wraps around the divs that contain the content. `#innerPageWrapper` also does act visually as a semi-transparent border in the layout.

My problem is that `#innerPageWrapper` won't expand to fit the children inside, let alone expand to fill the rest of the page.

This is the code for `#innerPageWrapper`

```
#innerPageWrapper {
    width: 1100px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) url(navShadow.png) repeat-x top;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

I have tried many things (including using calc() for div heights) unsuccessfully. I want to avoid using jQuery.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Firstly, you are using `height:100%;` which **in your case** is wrong. For an explanation on why not to use `height:100%`, check [this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm) article;

> To understand why, you need to understand how browsers interpret
>   height and width. Web browsers calculate the total available width as
>   a function of how wide the browser window is opened. If you don't set
>   any width values on your documents, the browser will automatically
>   flow the contents to fill the entire width of the window.
>
> But height is calculated differently. In fact, browsers don't evaluate
>   height at all unless the content is so long that it goes outside of
>   the view port (thus requiring scroll bars) or if the web designer sets
>   an absolute height on an element on the page. Otherwise, the browser
>   simply lets the content flow within the width of the view port until
>   it comes to the end. The height is not calculated at all. The problem
>   occurs when you set a percentage height on an element who's parent
>   elements don't have heights set. In other words, the parent elements
>   have a default height: auto;. You are, in effect, asking the browser
>   to calculate a height from an undefined value. Since that would equal
>   a null-value, the result is that the browser does nothing.

Secondly, to make the outer-div (in this case *#innerPageWrapper*) wrap around the child elements, you should use `overflow:hidden` on this wrapper.

For this to successfully work, your child elements must **not**  be `position:absolute` as you have for *#contentMain* and *#contentSidebar*, instead make these *floats* (*float:left* and *float:right*) and after the *#contentSidebar* div closes, add a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` to clear floats, allowing the parent to wrap around them perfectly.

I have put the required CSS in [this](http://pastebin.com/gv3q2tRx) Pastebin, note that you must clear your floats using a div as I mentioned above.

Comment: It works! Thanks. That article was a good read too. I will be re-writing my code from scratch taking into account those guidelines. thanks

Comment: `overflow:hidden` on the wrapper did the trick in my case. For those, like me, wondering why, here's a discussion on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19972790/3136474

Comment: Make sure that the child hasn't got position:absolute

Comment: Check if you have a `line-height` directive, it can enforce height as well.

Answer (score 13):

Try setting width and height of the parent element to auto. 
Simplified example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kimgysen/8nWDE/

```
#innerPageWrapper {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background:red;
}

#innerPageWrapper p{
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background: yellow;
}
```

**Edit:**

Check this fiddle for a more advanced example, including horizontal and vertical center: http://jsfiddle.net/kimgysen/8nWDE/1/

The parent element will dynamically adapt to the bounds of the child elements.
You can also set dynamic width and height on child elements.

```
.outerDiv{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: auto; 
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.innerDiv{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Of all the million other fixes in the top answers, this worked for me. Simply putting the parent's height on auto!